# Question about the complex function $f(z)=e^{z}(z-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

There is an exercise about the complex function $f(z)=e^{z}(z-1)$. It asks for find the imaginary and real parts of this function. If $z=x+iy$, then $e^z=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$ and $z-1=(x-1)+iy$. So $$\Re(e^{z}(z-1))=e^x((x-1)\cos y-y\sin y).$$ Is there anything else to do about it? Is there something special about this function?

Comment: you wrote $z^z$

Comment: You also wrote $\cos x$ instead of $\cos y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the 2 edits, the current version of your calculation is correct and this is a reasonable final answer. You aren't missing any super insightful way to simplify further or anything.

Bonus note: If you want to check your work on further problems like this, you can use WolframAlpha with a query like `ComplexExpand[(x + I y - 1) Exp[x + I y]]`. Here's an example [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=ComplexExpand%5C%2891%29%5C%2840%29x%20%2B%20I%20y%20-%201%5C%2841%29%20Exp%5Bx%20%2B%20I%20y%5D%5C%2893%29).